# oci_fetch_* returns less rows than Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I'm running a very simple query in both Oracle SQL Developer and via PHP / OCI / Instaclient and I'm getting differing numbers of rows!

```
select * from T_MYTABLE where FOO = 'BAR';
```

Code:

```
$connectionString = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.10)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=MYSID)))";
$conn = oci_connect($username, $passwort, $connectionString);
$ps1 = oci_parse($conn, "ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE = GERMAN_GERMANY.UTF8;");
oci_execute($ps1);

$sql = "select * from T_MYTABLE where FOO = 'BAR'";
$ps2 = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
$r = oci_execute($ps2);

while ($row = oci_fetch_array($ps2, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    print_r($row);
    echo "\n";
}
```

Here is the ID column of my SQL Developer result, next to it is the order in which PHP receives these rows:

```
ID
663257   1
773255   9
778802   8
778799   7
773250   6
806716   5
808275   4
806721   3
808280   2
826381   NOT INCLUDED
826383   NOT INCLUDED
```

There used to be a "ORDER BY ID" in the query, but I left it out since I've got the feeling this behaviour might be a hint at the inner workings of Oracle. It's as if, when approaching the database from the OCI side, it doesn't know about those two last (newest) lines.

I really don't get what's going on here. I'm used to MySQL, where the same query will give you the same result...

Yes, I'm running exactly the same query in both cases.

Yes, I'm accessing the same database.

Comment: Please give a [MCVE] including the code for PHP, any initialisation parameters for OCI/Instaclient and the DDL statement for the table. The answer might relate to data types (especially something like [blank-padded comparison semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37367779/1509264)) or it might be that OCI is paginating results (although I would be surprised at that).

Comment: I added a code example. I also tried LIKE '%BAR%' variations to avoid invisible character problems. No difference. I restricted the result to IDs > 800000, still 2 rows missing, so no pagination problem. I'm only querying on column based on a fixed string, so unless the data is "invisibly different", blank-padding shouldn't play a role either, but thanks!

Comment: One other thing to check - were the two rows that are not showing inserted in the session that is running via SQL developer and the rows are not committed? If that was the case then they would be visible to that session but not to other sessions. You could run `COMMIT;` or `ROLLBACK;` in SQL Developer (as appropriate) and see whether the result set then matches.

Comment: Good idea, I remembert seeing that in another question here on SO, but no, the data was inserted weeks ago by a completely different application. *sigh*

Comment: WEIRD - only thought is, do you have Preferences > Database > NLS > Language also set to 'German' in SQL Developer?

Comment: Yep, it's German too. Still, it shouldn't matter were it different, since this is an expensive enterprise grade database which surely wouldn't do weird stuff, right? ;)

Comment: Not related to question, but good practice - you should use bind variables instead of hard-coding values in a query in order to prevent SQL injection. In your case it won't happen because you are not using variable that may have been compromised (from GET or POST), but you should be aware of this. Your query should be 'select * from T_MYTABLE where FOO = :foo', and you should use oci_bind_by_name to bind variable :foo to value 'BAR'. Obviously you can change name of the bind variable to whatever you want.

Comment: As for the question - add 'echo oci_num_rows($ps2) . "\n"' before while loop. Also try executing query select count(*) from t_mytable where foo = 'BAR' to see how many rows there are for filter on foo column - it may be that something weird happened when PHP tried to display result of the query in a loop.

Comment: oci_num_rows() "does not return number of rows selected" http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-num-rows.php

Comment: The count(*) query gives my 9 rows as well.

Comment: Yes, you are right about oci_num_rows, sorry about that. Are you absolutely certain that you are fetching from the same table (same schema, same database, same table), and that there are no inserts/updates/deletes that may have been uncommitted? Is there a public synonym with the same name in the DB? If yes, what is its underlying object? Is there a view with the same name in the DB?

Comment: Add some trace statements to confirm you are actually connected to what you think you are.  Try the same alter & query in SQL*Plus (running on the same machine as PHP, and using the same Oracle 'client' libraries).  This uses a tech stack closer to PHP than SQLDev does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, I'm an idiot!

Goran Stefanović gave me the right hint, I was still connecting to our "old" (i. e. before virtualization) Oracle server.

**If you encounter the problem mentioned in this topic: DO TURN OFF ANY UNNEEDED ORACLE INSTANCES**