# when we need trim when we don't need in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle I see, some time `'A  ' = 'A'`, but some time `'A  ' != 'A'`, Please see example below you will see detail. I has been try to short the code.

```
CREATE TABLE AAA (
    T1 CHAR(3),
    T2 VARCHAR(3),
    T3 VARCHAR(5)
);
insert into AAA
SELECT 'A','A  ', 'A    ' FROM DUAL;
COMMIT;
SELECT * FROM AAA WHERE T1 = 'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT  * FROM AAA WHERE T2 = 'A  '
UNION ALL
SELECT  * FROM AAA WHERE T2 = 'A    '
UNION ALL
SELECT  * FROM AAA WHERE TRIM(T2) = TRIM('A   ')
UNION ALL
SELECT CASE WHEN 'A' = 'A ' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END T1, 
       CASE WHEN 'A       ' = 'A' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END T2,
       CASE WHEN 'A ' = 'A ' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END T2   
FROM DUAL;
```

I ask this question because in my db, When I join table A to table B some time we TRIM(A.ID) = TRIM(B.REFID) some time we don't need to do this. When we need TRIM(column)? When `'A  ' = 'A'` ? and when `'A  ' != 'A'`?

[image]

Comment: You'd normalize the data when you want or need looser matching.

` 'Password' = TRIM('   Password       ') ` could be very bad.

Comment: Ideally you wouldn't need to use `TRIM` if you scrub the data and remove leading/trailing whitespace before bringing the data into your table.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I know, but this data has been existed along time, There is a lot of column like this.

Comment: I think you can try to use `T1 || '^' = 'A^'` (add addition char in the end) if you need to do exact comparison. Alas, I don't have Oracle now and I can't check it.

Comment: I know, exact comparison is trim(), it ok, But some time if we don't compare 2 table care we can make a mistake easily.

Comment: Are the 2 checks in the question title correct ? they look exactly the same, I assume you meant them to be different ? `some time 'A  ' = 'A', but some time 'A  ' = 'A'`

Comment: @ Veverke thanks, I has been edit it. so sorry

Comment: Mostly answered in [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37366588/1509264) but I've added some more complete examples in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the Oracle Documentation on [literals](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm):

> Text literals have properties of both the `CHAR` and `VARCHAR2` datatypes:
>
> - Within expressions and conditions, Oracle treats text literals as though they have the datatype `CHAR` by comparing them using blank-padded comparison semantics.

and the documentation of [blank-padded comparison semantics](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements002.htm#BABJJGBI) states:

> With blank-padded semantics, if the two values have different lengths, then Oracle first adds blanks to the end of the shorter one so their lengths are equal. Oracle then compares the values character by character up to the first character that differs. The value with the greater character in the first differing position is considered greater. If two values have no differing characters, then they are considered equal. This rule means that two values are equal if they differ only in the number of trailing blanks. Oracle uses blank-padded comparison semantics only when both values in the comparison are either expressions of datatype **`CHAR`**, **`NCHAR`**, text literals, or values returned by the **`USER`** function.

So, for your examples:

```
SELECT * FROM AAA WHERE T1 = 'A'
```

Since the left-hand side of the comparison, `T1` which equals `'A  '`, is a `CHAR(3)` and the right-hand side is a text literal `'A'` then blank-padded comparison semantics are used and `'A  ' = 'A'` is true.

Then:

```
SELECT  * FROM AAA WHERE T2 = 'A  '
```

The left-hand side of the comparison, `T2` which equals `'A  '`, is a `VARCHAR2(3)` and the right-hand side is a text literal `'A  '` then blank-padded comparison semantics are not used (both sides are not `CHAR` or text literals) but the values are equal (`'A  ' = 'A  '`) so the condition is true.

And:

```
SELECT  * FROM AAA WHERE T2 = 'A    '
```

The LHS is a `VARCHAR2` equal to `'A  '` and the RHS is a text literal equal to `'A     '`; blank-padded comparison semantics will not be used and the values are not equal so the condition is not true and the row will not be returned.

Then:

```
SELECT  * FROM AAA WHERE TRIM(T2) = TRIM('A   ')
```

The [`TRIM()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions199.htm) states that:

> The string returned is of `VARCHAR2` datatype if trim_source is a character datatype and a `LOB` if trim_source is a `LOB` datatype.

Both values are trimmed so you have the condition `'A' = 'A'` where both sides are a `VARCAHR2` data type so blank-padded comparison semantics will not be used but the values are equal so the condition is true and the row will be returned.

Finally:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 'A' = 'A ' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END T1, 
       CASE WHEN 'A       ' = 'A' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END T2,
       CASE WHEN 'A ' = 'A ' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END T2   
FROM DUAL;
```

In all cases both sides of the equality are text literals so blank-padded comparison semantics will be used so for

- `'A' = 'A '` the LHS will be padded so the strings are the same length;
- `'A       ' = 'A'` the RHS will be padded;
- `'A ' = 'A '` both sides are equal length so no padding is needed.

And in each case the equalities are equal.

If you use `CAST` to change from text literals to a `VARCHAR2` data type:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 'A' = CAST( 'A ' AS VARCHAR2(5) ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS T1
FROM   DUAL
```

The LHS is a text literal but the RHS is a `VARCHAR2` and blank-padded comparison semantics are not used and the equality is not true.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am linking to an answer where the appropriate documentation is quoted so that future users have a concise and official explanation for the behaviour (rather than having to decipher the ASKTOM link in your question which has no formatting so is not easy to read and also does not link to the documentation so the full conditions when blank padded comparison semantics are used are not explored). I could have equally linked to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47326316/1509264) that also has the documentation but linking to this one is more relevant.

Answer (score 2):

I think the behavior your are seeing when querying your actual table is expected, and the only behavior which might surprise you is in the following query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 'A' = 'A ' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END T1, 
       CASE WHEN 'A       ' = 'A' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END T2,
       CASE WHEN 'A ' = 'A ' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END T2   
FROM DUAL;
```

From [this Oracle discussion](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:59852033114407), it appears that what is happening has to do with that `'A'`, `'A '`, etc. are `char` types and *not* `varchar2` types.  As a result, in order to compare two `char` values they need to be the same length.  Consider the following `CASE` expression:

```
CASE WHEN 'A       ' = 'A' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END T2
```

Here the `'A'` literal, which is a `char(1)`, will be promoted to `char(8)` by padding on the right with spaces.  So when the comparsion actually takes place, both the LHS and RHS are actually the same.  Note that the following `CASE` expression would not evaluate to the true condition:

```
CASE WHEN '  A' = 'A' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END T2
```

This is because the padding would happen to `'A'` on the right, so `'  A'` would be compared against `'A  '`, which are not the same.

Follow the link below for a demo which shows that if you use all `varchar` columns that the original spaces/widths of the inputs are preserved, and the logical comparison of strings is what you would expect.

### Demo

Comment: The behavior for text literals is not unexpected and is defined within the oracle documentation (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47326316/1509264))

Comment: @MT0 I was saying unintended from the point of view of the OP.  Of course, this behavior is known and Oracle is a decades old database.