# Query between char and varchar returns nothing

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I have the following query:

```
datacollector_cursor.execute(f"SELECT CNP FROM tblclient WHERE CNP='{str(row[0])}'")
aux = datacollector_cursor.fetchall()
```

Where **CNP** is a varchar variable and **row[0]** is char type. The issue is that this query never returns anything even if the two should be equal. I've manually replaced **row[0]** with an actual variable that meets the requirements and it outputs what I need. Why isn't this comparison correct?

Comment: Have you inspected what `str(row[0])` returns? Or how your final query looks? Try to print it out before executing it.

Comment: What Python library are you using here to access Oracle?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/47322354/1509264

Comment: Don't use string concatenation (or a template string) to build queries as that is how you get SQL injection vulnerabilities; instead you should pass the values using bind variables.

Comment: I don't know Python, but doesn't `str(row[0])` return a Python string, which I'm guessing converts to an Oracle `varchar2` and not `char` (which is a distinct datatype in Oracle)? Also, `CNP` seems to be a table column and not a variable, so I am not sure what you mean by *CNP is a varchar variable and row[0] is char type*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't build queries using string concatenation (or template strings) as that is how you introduce SQL injection vulnerabilities into your code.

Instead, use bind variables. If you are [using `cx_Oracle`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html):

```python
sql = "SELECT CNP FROM tblclient WHERE CNP=:value"
datacollector_cursor.execute(sql, [str(row[0])])
aux = datacollector_cursor.fetchall()
```

If you are having problems with [blank padding semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47326316/1509264) then you can use `TRIM`:

```python
sql = "SELECT CNP FROM tblclient WHERE TRIM(RIGHT ' ' FROM CNP)=TRIM(RIGHT ' ' FROM :value)"
datacollector_cursor.execute(sql, [str(row[0])])
aux = datacollector_cursor.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 1):

CHAR() are always filled with spaces up to their declared size in the table DDL, so `'ABC' as varchar2(6) != 'ABC   '` as char(6).