# Oracle JOIN 2 tables on fields CHAR with different sizes

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an external software that uses Oracle 19.1.0 in which we have 2 tables that I'd like to join. In one table one of the join field is `CHAR(15)` and in the other it's `CHAR(36)`. I know that in the second table the field is filled with blanks at the end (after position 15).

When I try to execute a query this way it doesn't return any rows:

```sql
SELECT C30.C30_FILIAL FILIAL,
        C30.C30_CHVNF CHVNF,
        C30.C30_NUMITE NUMITE,
        C30.C30_CODITE CODITE,
        C30.C30_TPREPA TPREPA,
        C30.C30_IDTSER IDTSER,
        C30.C30_SRVMUN SRVMUN,
        C30.C30_CODSER CODSER 
    FROM TSC00_1568128481 C20 
        INNER JOIN C30010 C30 
            ON C30.C30_CHVNF = C20.CHVNF
                AND C30.C30_FILIAL = C20.FILIAL 
                AND C30.D_E_L_E_T_ =' '
```

But when I try with a RTRIM it works as expected returning several rows:

```sql
SELECT C30.C30_FILIAL FILIAL,
        C30.C30_CHVNF CHVNF,
        C30.C30_NUMITE NUMITE,
        C30.C30_CODITE CODITE,
        C30.C30_TPREPA TPREPA,
        C30.C30_IDTSER IDTSER,
        C30.C30_SRVMUN SRVMUN,
        C30.C30_CODSER CODSER 
    FROM TSC00_1568128481 C20 
        INNER JOIN C30010 C30 
            ON C30.C30_CHVNF = RTRIM(C20.CHVNF)
                AND C30.C30_FILIAL = C20.FILIAL 
                AND C30.D_E_L_E_T_ =' '
```

`C30010.C30_CHVNF` is `CHAR(15)` and `C20.CHVNF` is `CHAR(36)`. I don't have access to rewrite the query.

[Execution plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgfWA.png)

Is there any parameter that controls this?

Comment: Since you cannot change the query, what's your question?

Comment: I don't know about Oracle 19, but ISO SQL (_ANSI/ISO SQL-92 specification (Section 8.2, Comparison Predicate, General rules #3)_) requires DB engines to normalize values used in string-comparisons, including _widening_ shorter strings to match - so your initial query _should work_ as-is - I'm guessing Oracle has a configuration option to opt-in or opt-out of ISO SQL comparison logic?

Comment: Are you certain the types are `char(15)` and `char(36)` and not `varchar2` or `nvarchar2` ?

Comment: `CHAR` pads inserted values with spaces until it reaches the defined fixed-width. That's why nearly everybody uses `VARCHAR2` instead, which is variable width and does no padding (you can still insert a trailing space, but you'd be requesting it in that case). Unless the column is a single flag (e.g. 'N', 'Y') or a small fixed width code that for sure never will change its width, you should avoid `CHAR` altogether.  In the mean time, you'll have to add the `RTRIM()`s to get the joins to work.

Comment: From your explain plan, we see that one column is CHAR and the other is VARCHAR2, that's why the db is behaving like this, and not as the first answer show

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/47322354/1509264 (which would mean your data types cannot both be `CHAR`s otherwise blank padded semantics rules would ensure that the shortest was padded to the length of the longest when comparing and they would be equal without using `RTRIM`, since this is not the behaviour you are seeing then one or both columns must not be a `CHAR`).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a function-based index on TSC00_1568128481 like below:

```
create index TSC00_1568128481_inf on TSC00_1568128481(RTRIM(CHVNF));
```

Still, I think it would be best to update that column so as to no longer contain spaces at the end and add constraint check(CHVNF=RTRIM(CHVNF)) and also, so as to prevent problems caused by the constraint create a trigger before update for each row that would apply rtrim to that column.

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Type-Comparison-Rules.html#GUID-A114F1F4-A08D-4107-B679-323DC7FEA31C__GUID-6F832501-CBAF-4F38-B737-1A4BFEEC7C07), Oracle has different sorting rules depending on whether the values it is comparing are blank padded or not. Comparing two `CHAR` fields falls under the blank padded rules - i.e. the shortest field automatically gets space padded to the length of the longest field.

That means your CHAR fields should get compared ok without needing to be trimmed. You can see this in the db<>fiddles I created - one for [18c](https://dbfiddle.uk/lUy4c9hd) and one for [21c](https://dbfiddle.uk/hXm4XsYQ) (since db<>fiddle doesn't have a 19c version to run against).

```
create table t1 (col1 char(2));

create table t2 (col1 char(4));

insert into t1 (col1)
select 'aa' from dual union all
select 'bb' from dual;

insert into t2 (col1)
select 'aa  ' from dual union all
select 'cc  ' from dual;

select t1.col1 t1_col1, t2.col1 t2_col1, dump(t1.col1) dump_t1_col1, dump(t2.col1) dump_t2_col1
from   t1
       full outer join t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col1;

T1_COL1 T2_COL1 DUMP_T1_COL1        DUMP_T2_COL1
------- ------- ------------------- -------------------------
aa      aa      Typ=96 Len=2: 97,97 Typ=96 Len=4: 97,97,32,32
        cc      NULL                Typ=96 Len=4: 99,99,32,32
bb              Typ=96 Len=2: 98,98 NULL
```

Which leads me to think that Dai (from the comments on your question) is correct and the columns you're comparing aren't actually both CHAR columns.